# Как сделать так, чтобы при событии dblclick событие click игнорировалось бы?

Tags: javascript, события

Я установил для одного элемента два обработчика события для `click` и `dblclick`.

Например,

```
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("dblclick", function () { console.log("Bye"); }, false);
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function () { console.log("Hi"); }, false);
```

Однако при двойном нажатии мышки в IE-11 тем не менее событие `click` два раза перехватывается.

То есть получается

```
Hi
Hi
Bye
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при возникновении события `dblclick`  событие `click` игнорировалось бы?

Answer (score 9):

Простыми средствами - никак.
Проблема в том, что обработка кликов идет по порядку. Сначала `click`, потом `dblclick`, и надо, чтобы каким-то образом система предугадывала будет ли второй клик или нет. А она этого не может.

Как мне кажется, единственный вариант, это

- поставить `delay` на обработке `click`. Эта задержка даст возможность системе "дождаться" второго нажатия. Если второго нажатия не будет - пройдет событие одиночного клика.
- сделать обработку `dblclick`, которая бы отменяла функцию одиночного клика и запускала свою

Ну а если организовать JS функцию на общий клик, то все в одну согнать можно.
Что-то типа такого:

```
var waitingForClick = false;

function theClick(ev) {
    switch (ev.detail) {
    case 1: // первый клик
        waitingForClick = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Hi"); 
        }, 500);
        break;
    default: // больше чем один клик
        if (waitingForClick) { // отменить ждущий клик
            clearTimeout(waitingForClick);
            waitingForClick = false;
        }
        console.log("Bye");
        break;
    }
}

document.querySelector("div").addEventListener('click', theClick, false);
```

Comment: 1. Константа 500 мс - не панацея совершенно. Т.к. нет возможности узнать системный мышиный delay между кликами для получения даблклика.

Comment: 2. Рекомендую в дополнение к предложенному решению с ожиданием второго клика, ждать смещения курсора на n пикселей. Это позволит сократить ожидание пользователя в некоторых случаях.

Comment: @AlexanderKoz - о п.1 - согласен. Константа, пожалуй, самое слабое звено во всем коде. Но я не уверен, что что-то можно сделать для веб-приложения в этом случае. О п.2 - Вы советуете отменять таймер при движении мышки? Не думаю, что это разумно... Мышка ведь может просто дернуться в процессе первого нажатия. Мы отменим второй клик, а сработает одиночный...

Comment: прошу простить, не уточнил. Отменять таймер при смещении мышки далее, чем пороговая константа (например 2px, но зависит от DPI). Это метод, аналогичный распознаванию инициации драг-н-дропа на тач-девайсах - есть порог, до которого мы считаем, что касание для longTap, а при достижении/превышении порога (смещение) - уже startDrag.