# двойной клик для сохранения картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, есть картинка `<img src='img.png' download>` , есть ли какой то лайф-хак, чтобы картинка скачивалась не при обычном клике, а при двойном?

Comment: А где одиночный клик сохраняет картинку?

Comment: <img src='img.png' download>

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459692/256824

Answer (score 2):

У элемента [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) нет атрибута `download`.
Зато такой атрибут есть у элемента [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

---

Задачу можно решить так.
Поместить изображение `img` в ссылку `a` с атрибутом `download`.
Отлавливать событие `click` по `img` и останавливать его [всплытие](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling).
Отлавливать событие `dblclick` по `img` и генерировать событие `click` на родителе.

*Код примера:*

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

img.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

img.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
  this.parentElement.click();
});
```

```html
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats/1" download>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats/1" />
</a>
```

*Код примера jQuery:*

```js
$('img')
  .on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  })
  .on('dblclick', function(event) {
    $(this).parent()[0].click();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats/8" download>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats/8" />
</a>
```

---

Необходимо отметить, что не все  браузеры поддерживают атрибут `download`.
Например, *Internet Explorer* любой версии и некоторые версии *Safari* его не поддерживают.
Посмотреть поддержку браузерами: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download